# cannot set a breakpoint in gdb

Tags: fortran, gdb, mpi

I am trying to run a Fortran MPI code in gdb.  Compiled with GNU.  For the purposes of debugging, I am running with only one process.  I cannot get the code to actually stop at any breakpoint.  For instance, I want it to stop at line 1000, so I say

```
(gdb) break 1000
```

and everything seems OK.  It gives no error message.  And then I hit `run` and ... it runs right through my breakpoint.  I have made absolutely sure that the execution path is not at all sidestepping my breakpoint; the code at the breakpoint absolutely *is* being executed.

Anyone have an idea what the problem is?  Is it MPI-related?  Or something else?

Comment: Due to the lack of any information on how you run the debugger, I can only **guess** that you debug `mpirun` instead of the application.... Easiest is to use a proper MPI aware debugger of at least follow the documentation of your MPI implementation on debugging.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use simple trick:

```
mpirun -np 2 xterm -e gdb your_mpi_code
```

This way, you will end up with multiple gdb sessions, each running one of your MPI processes.

Make sure to compile code with `-g`

If you have money, to spent, take a look here:

https://www.roguewave.com/products-services/totalview